# mktemp with extension without specifying file path

Tags: bash, mktemp

Prefacing this with that I found identical questions but none of them have answers that are working for me.

I need to make a **temporary .json file** (it needs to be json because I'll be working with jq later in the script).

I thought based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419754/how-can-i-create-a-temp-file-with-a-specific-extension-in-bash) that it would be the following, but they're creating files named `.json` and `XXXXXXXX.json` respectively.

```
STACKS=$(mktemp .json)
STACKS=$(mktemp XXXXXXXX.json)
```

This will need to run on both mac OS, and a linux box. **I can't specify a path for the file** because it will be run both locally and by Jenkins, which have an unidentical file structure. What's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using openBSD `mktemp` you can

```
STACKS="$(mktemp XXXXXX).json"
```

and then write a `trap` so the tmps are removed when script finishes:

```
function cleanup {
    if [ -f "$STACKS" ] && [[ "$STACKS" =~ ".json"$ ]]; then
        rm -f "$STACKS"
    fi
}
trap cleanup EXIT
```

so when script finishes (no matter how) it will try to remove `$STACKS` if it is a file and if it ends with `.json` (for extra safety).

Comment: I get the following; `mktemp: illegal option -- -
usage: mktemp [-d] [-q] [-t prefix] [-u] template ...
       mktemp [-d] [-q] [-u] -t prefix`

Comment: what shell are you using? are you positive it's bash? also, what does mktemp --version says?

Comment: yes bash (just checked with `echo $0` to confirm), and mktemp --version gives me the same error, `illegal option -- -` etc

Comment: how about `mktemp -V`? or `-v`? i belive you are using mktemp from openBSD rather than the one from GNU Coreutils

Comment: both -V and -v are giving me illegal option errors, does that support your theory?

Comment: apparently yes, check this cli interface: http://man.openbsd.org/mktemp.1 what system are you running, mac OS?

Comment: yep, we use macs for work so I'm stuck on mac OS. I could test in a VM but this may be run locally by coworkers so a mac friendly script is necessary.

Comment: check if you have an implementation of `mkstemps` in mac OS, which permits templates to have a suffix, so your example of `XXXXXXX.json` should be valid. check `mkstemps` as an extension for mktemp here (note the s): http://www.manpages.info/macosx/mktemp.3.html

Comment: Nope, I take that back. I can view the man page for it but get a bash mkstemps: command not found error

Comment: oops, sorry, my bad, that was from the C library. sorry, i don't think i can help you with a generic solution unless this workaround is of any interest to you `STACKS="$(mktemp XXXXXX).json"`

Comment: it looks like that works but doesn't remove the file after the script finishes. If you can include a reliable way to delete the file afterwards (and edit your post to match) I'd be happy to accept your answer! (and either way, thanks for your help)

Comment: i updated the answer, i think a `trap` can handle what you mean by "realiable way"

Comment: Not sure if this would guarantee uniqueness of the generated file name. Suppose the generated prefix is /tmp/temp.abcdef but the file /tmp/temp.abcdef.ps already exists?